# When I try to remove a UITableViewCell, I get this error: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0, but I can't seem to fix it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I have a gesture on a UITableViewCell subclass called ArticleCell, so when it is swiped a method in the UITableViewController class gets called to delete the cell that was swiped.

The delegate method looks like this:

```
- (void)swipedToRemoveCell:(ArticleCell *)articleCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:articleCell];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But every time I swipe, I get this error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

More information: It uses Core Data for the data source, so it uses NSFetchedResultsController. Do I have to update something there? (I haven't touched any of its methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to also remove the row from your data source object as well. You will need to remove it from your Core Data store at the same time as you delete the row representing the data from the table view itself.

The issue is this mismatch, you remove the row from the table view but your `-numberOfRowsInTableView` data source method is still returning the old number of rows because the fetched results controller still sees that number in the data store.

Answer (score 1):

it is happening because when you are deleting the row but you are not deleting the actual object from the list, therefore it is returning wrong number of counts for rows or either for section. you should update your list as well.

One more thing you don't need to reload your data as it is doing already when you deleting the row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this directly by removing that object from array and reloading tableView after that:

```
- (void)swipedToRemoveCell:(ArticleCell *)articleCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:articleCell];

    [DATASOURCE_ARRAY removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Here DATASOURCE_ARRAY is the array you are using as datasource of tableView
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using core data , you can do this

In your delete action call this code

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
```

Overwrite this fetchcontroller delegate ....

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableViewIB;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```